# setTimeout() in Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, settimeout

I am writing cloud functions on Cloud Firestore triggers. What I want is when a document is added under some uuid it has to deleted after 2 minutes and assign the same data to another document. I wrote some code regarding that like below

```
exports.createdOpenOrder = functions.firestore.document('Some/{psId}/Open/{OrderId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
    // Get an object representing the document
    console.log("Deleting function execution started:");

    const newValue = snap.data();
    var OrderId = context.params.OrderId;
    var psId = context.params.psId;

    setTimeout(delete_cur, 120000);

    function delete_cur() {

        var data = db.collection('Some').doc(psId).collection('Open').doc(OrderId).delete().then(function() {
            console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
            // calling another function to reassign
            reassign(OrderId);
            return;
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
            return;
        });

     }

});
```

Now my problem is the setTimeout function is not calling exactly after 2 minutes and data is not deleting. Is anything wrong with my code? Please let me know how to write code work perfectly on setTimeout.

Comment: I think your code seems to be ok problem lies on your var data statement, COuld you please put console statement on delete_cur and verify your seTimeout working or not

Comment: Use `console.time("someUniqueLabel")` right before you call setTimeout and `console.timeEnd("someUniqueLabel")` inside setTimeout. You will see how long setTimeout is _actually_ taking. Just make sure that every `time` has a matching `timeEnd` with the save unique label.

Comment: You're not returning a promise that resolves when all the async work is complete in your function.  This is a hard requirement for background functions.  You can't use setTimeout to schedule work to execute after the function fully completes - that's not supported.  When a function returns without a promise and leaves unresolved async work running, that work will almost certainly be shut down by Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 1):

To find the problem, put log before, and a catch around, the contents of your setTimeout handler.

Currently you are only trapping exceptions after the `delete` async function returns.  All other exceptions in the chain, before calling `delete`, are not caught.

```
function delete_cur() {
  console.log('handler called')
  try {
    var data = db.collection('Some').doc(psId).collection('Open').doc(OrderId).delete().then(function() {
      console.log("Document successfully deleted!");
      // calling another function to reassign
      reassign(OrderId);
      return;
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error removing document: ", error);
      return;
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('could not invoke delete', e)
  }

}
```